# How to include header and footer in HTML files using handlebars

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I would like to include header.html and footer.html in every HTML pages of my website using Handlebars. I've done some tutorials about Handlebars so I know how to include some text but I didn't find how to include a file.

Do you know if I can do that with Handlebars and how?

Comment: Have you tried using this? http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Yes but it's not to add a complete file, just to add some text. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are [handlebars partials](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partials).

> Handlebars allows for template reuse through partials. Partials are normal Handlebars templates that may be called directly by other templates.

**Basic example:**

> In order to use a partial, it must be registered via `Handlebars.registerPartial()`.

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('myPartial', '{{name}}');
```

> This call will register the myPartial partial. Partials may be precompiled and the precompiled template passed into the second parameter.
> Calling the partial is done through the partial call syntax:

```
{{> myPartial }}
```

> Will render the partial named myPartial. When the partial executes, it will be run under the current execution context.